# Coq - How to prove eqb_neq?

Tags: coq, proof, coqide

I'm trying to prove `eqb_neq`:

```
Theorem eqb_neq : forall x y : nat,
  x =? y = false <-> x <> y.
```

This is my current proof status: 
[image]

During the proof I reached a final step where I just need to prove the additional helper theorem:

```
Theorem eqb_false_helper : forall n m : nat,
    n <> m -> S n <> S m.
```

I've tried multiple strategies but now I'm not even sure it's possible to prove this helper theorem.

I'm not sure how to prove the base case using induction: 
[image]

What else can I try? Any tips for `eqb_neq` or the helper theorem?

Thanks

Comment: I have to kindly ask you to refrain from posting (partial) solutions to SF exercises on public forums. If you can repost your question to remove your proof, we'd be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple for your helper theorem if you just unfold not :

```
Theorem eqb_false_helper : forall n m : nat,
    n <> m -> S n <> S m.
Proof.
unfold not; intros.
apply H; injection H0; intro; assumption.
Qed.
```

You actually just need to prove that `S n = S m -> False`, you assume that `n = m -> False`, thus you can prove that `S n = S m -> n = m`, which is done injecting hypothesis `S n = S m`.